# Help me locate where is XML being generated

Tags: xml

my client is using **Expression Engine 1.6.8** and there are some broken XML documents created with page. I have no experience with Expression Engine. The problem is these dinamic XML is being generated - so others pages can use it as source.

**The problem:** I have no idea where this XML is being generated.

This is very broad question but : Where is this XML being generated and how can I fix it? Where to check? What is usual practice?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have a url to the xml?

Answer (score 1):

All pages are generated by templates. Take a look at the [templates section of control panel](http://ee1docs.com/cp/templates/templates.html).